# Mongodb array manipulation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've problem with array manipulation in mongodb. I will show on example what I need.

**My collection structure:**

```js
{ id: "user1", items: [ { id: "1", quantity: 1 }, { id: "2", quantity: 3 } ] }

{ id: "user2", items: [ { id: "1", quantity: 1 }, { id: "3", quantity: 3 } ] }
```

**I would like add some items for user1.**

If items with id exist already in user array I would like to just increment quantity. If not I would like add it to items list.

**In example:**

I would like to add items `[ { id: "1", quantity: 1 }, { id: "3", quantity: 1 } ]` for user1

After this operation structure of collection should look like:

```js
{ id: "user1", items: [ { id: "1", **quantity: 2** }, { id: "2", quantity: 3 }, **{ id: "3", quantity: 1 }**  ] }

{ id: "user2", items: [ { id: "1", quantity: 1 }, { id: "3", quantity: 3 } ] }
```

How to do it? Aggregation? Map reduce? I don't want to make query for each of added element.

Comment: Look at the `$set` and `$push` operators of MongoDB

Comment: Thanks for answer. I can use pushAll to add everything by one query to array. But then it will look like: { id: "user1", items: [ { id: "1", quantity: 1 }, { id: "2", quantity: 3 }, { id: "3", quantity: 1 }, { id: "1", quantity: 1 } ] }. That's not that I need.

Answer (score 2):

To change object value use [$set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/):

```
'$set':{quantity: 1}
```

For increment you can use [$inc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/)

```
$inc: { quantity: 5 }
```

To add new item in array use [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push):

```
$push: { quantity: 0 }
```

Chek all array operations here: [Array Update Operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-array/)

Comment: Ye, thanks. I know that I can do it from N [just inc] to 2*N [checking if can inc - if not already in array then push] queries (where N is length of pushed array). Just wonder if I can do it by less work.